# config.js:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: firebase is not defined in React propject compiled by webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, webpack

I am doing a React project, I want to use several firebase/firestre module, however it show me [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqNVy.png)
I checked my webpack package.json, there is `"firebase": "^9.6.11",` under `"dependencies"`,

and i also init the firebase with Firestore and configure hosting.
Here is my chatbox.js file, maybe it can perform more detail.

```
import React from "react";
import {getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, signInWithEmailAndPassword} from "firebase/auth";
import {collection, getDoc, getDocs, addDoc, updateDoc, setDoc, Timestamp, doc} from "firebase/firestore";
import {db} from "../config";

function write_message(chatroomID, message) {
    console.log(getAuth().currentUser.uid + ' is sending message \"' + message + '\" to ' + chatroomID)
    var chatroom_docref = doc(db, collection(db ,'chatroom'), chatroomID);
    updateDoc(chatroom_docref, {
        last_time: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
        last_text: message,
        msg_count: chatroom_docref.msg_count + 1
    });
    var messages_colref = collection(db, chatroom_docref + '\\messages')
    setDoc(doc(db, collection(db, messages_colref, chatroomID + chatroom_docref.msg_count)), {
        people: getAuth().currentUser.uid,
        time: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
        text: message,
        msg_ID: chatroomID + chatroom_docref.msg_count
    })
}
```

My project is due within 10 hours, pls someone help......
Moreover, there is several [warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er1ev.png) more below the Uncaught Reference Error

Comment: Are you sure the error is from the code block  that you've provided? Are you trying to use "firebase" somewhere but that's not declared.

Comment: Nevermind, I just found out that it is because the {db} from config is modified due to git reset